Bitnami Postgresql Image deploy on OpenShift
Trying to deploy Bitnami Postgresql in Openshift cluster.
Have modified the values.yaml, with the recommended values for openshift from the readme.
i.e.

For OpenShift 4.11 and higher, let set OpenShift the runAsUser and fsGroup automatically. Configure the pod and container security context to restrictive defaults and disable the volume permissions setup: primary.

podSecurityContext.fsGroup=null,
primary.podSecurityContext.seccompProfile.type=RuntimeDefault,
primary.containerSecurityContext.runAsUser=null,
primary.containerSecurityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation=false,
primary.containerSecurityContext.runAsNonRoot=true,
primary.containerSecurityContext.seccompProfile.type=RuntimeDefault,
primary.containerSecurityContext.capabilities.drop=['ALL'],
volumePermissions.enabled=false,
shmVolume.enabled=false

But after installing the helm chart, i get the below error
postgresql git:(sonarqube) ✗ oc logs pod/sonarqube-postgresql-0 exec /opt/bitnami/scripts/postgresql/entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Could someone please assist me in identifying what I might be overlooking? I'm encountering an issue while deploying the Bitnami PostgreSQL Helm chart in my OpenShift cluster. Specifically, I'm getting an error when trying to execute the entrypoint script (entrypoint.sh). The error message, exec format error, suggests that there could be an issue with the script's format or execution or permission issues.

Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

The exec format error indicates that you are running a container from an unsupported architecture.
Maybe a linux/amd64 on a darwin/arm64 architecture or the opposite.
If needed you can use buildx to cross-build the container such as:
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t <container-name>:<version> .

for cross-building a linux/amd64 container from another architecture.
